# mysqldump command not found - MAMP

Tags: mysql, terminal, dump

How can I add mysqldump to the export path when running MAMP. I have tried a few export commands I found via google but with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

First find here the binary is using "whereis mysqldump"

Then: 
PATH=$PATH:PATH_FROM_ABOVE_COMMAND
export PATH